# Copy Format Conditions from one cell to another?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to be able to write something like:

```
wks.Range("A1").FormatConditions = r.FormatConditions
```

to copy conditional formatting from one cell to another. Is this possible to do? I want to copy conditional formatting from one cell to another by using one line of code, just like when I copy a formulas from one cell to another:

```
wks.Range("A1").Formula = r.Formula
```

Maybe there is a built-in command for this in VBA that I have not found?
Maybe someone has written a custom sub for this?

r in the above examples is a range.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it using one line of code.  However, you can do it using two lines:

```
wks.Range("A1").Copy
r.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

This will copy all the formatting including the format conditions.

Comment: This also copies more than just the conditional formatting but I can deal with it.