# Copy only conditional formatting

Tags: vba, excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

I am struggling with something that seems fairly simple. I am trying to copy **just** the conditional formatting rules of a cell to another. I have searched for similar questions here:

1) [Copy Format Conditions from one cell to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901104/copy-format-conditions-from-one-cell-to-another)

and elsewhere:

1) https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/9956-solved-macro-to-copy-conditional-formatting

2) https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/369089-vba-copy-conditional-formatting.html

...but most answers tend to just say to use `.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats`, which 9 times out of 10 does the job, but is not a true answer to what I am trying to do (see the comment from a user on the SO question: "This also copies more than just the conditional formatting but I can deal with it").

I am trying to take the conditional formatting rules from one cell and apply them to another cell that is formatted differently as standard. Judging by this set of examples of `.PasteSpecial` enums there isn't one that does the exact job - `xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats` looks like it comes close but I don't actually want to paste anything from one cell to another.

Tried a few hopeless guesses like:

`For Each cond In rng1.FormatConditions
    rng2.FormatConditions.Add (cond)
 Next cond`

But I know it needs more than that... Any help appreciated!

Comment: The paste special dialog does have an option called "All Merging Conditional Formats", does that work for you?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned this in my question but it isn't quite right.. so close.. but not just conditional formatting rules. See further detail in the comments of Vityata's answer below. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a cheap trick (a.k.a. "The Swap"), but it should work. Let's say that you care only for the following properties:

- Font.Name
- Font.Size
- Interior.Color

Thus, before copying the cell, you can simply remember the properties in a "hiddenRange". Thus, you can simply copy the `copyRange` to the `hiddenRange`, then copy the `copyRange` to the `pasteRange` with `xlPasteAllMerginingConditionalFormats` and then recall the correct properties of the `pasteRange` from the `hiddenRange`.

It is a bit better to be seen than explained:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim hiddenRange As Range
    Dim copyRange   As Range
    Dim pasteRange  As Range

    Set hiddenRange = Range("A1")
    Set copyRange = Range("B2")
    Set pasteRange = Range("B3")

    pasteRange.Copy hiddenRange
    copyRange.Copy
    pasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats

    With pasteRange
        .Font.Name = hiddenRange.Font.Name
        .Font.Size = hiddenRange.Font.Size
        .Interior.Color = hiddenRange.Interior.Color
    End With

    hiddenRange.Clear
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does more than just copy the conditional formats.. I tested it and you can try too - using B2 with a blue background, font Algerian size 15, B3 with a yellow background, font Arial Black size 12. When you copy the formatting rule, B3 takes on the rule perfectly, but when the condition is not met (i.e. when nothing is happening and I want the cell to look 'standard'), B3 has taken on the same formatting as B2 - it has lost its yellow background, Arial Black font and font size. I hope this makes sense

Comment: I tested a bit and come to the conclusion that the AllMergingConditionalFormats is not what you need as what that does is paste the resulting formatting of the copied cell as that cell displays it, it does NOT paste the conditional formatting itself. So I expect the only way to achieve what you need is to duplicate the entire CF rule for the new range. If you record a macro where you manually update the range to which the CF rule applies, you'll see the macro recorder records: 1. Delete existing CF rules for the range. 2. Reapply the CF rule to the new range.

Comment: @jkpieterse - actually it copies exactly the conditional format. Which is strange, because when I first read your comment, I have tried it and it seemed that it did not copy at all. Now I am trying again and it copies the format exactly as it should be. Have you tried with `B2` and `B3` from my code? `B2` is the cell with the previously implemented format and `B3` should obtain the format only after the code is ran.

Comment: The odd thing is, I tried doing it manually (not with VBA code!) using a small sample workbook and when pasting manually using hte all merging conditional formatting option, it pasted both the value and the resulting formatting, but NOT the CF rule itself.